# Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:5.2.4:check

Tags: maven, owasp, mojo

I'm getting error for configuration entry 'formats', which am not able to find under dependency-check-maven-5.2.4.pom & dependency-check-parent-5.2.4.pom

> Unable to parse configuration of mojo org.owasp:dependency-check-maven:5.2.4:check for parameter formats: Cannot assign configuration entry 'formats' with value 'HTML,XML' of type java.lang.String to property of type java.lang.String[]

Any pointers to fix the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this for us was to update the build pipeline to use Maven 3.6.0. Before, it was running a low 3.X.X version of Maven. It seems like the new Maven is able to handle this.